# CheckBox binding wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a checkBox which is bound on the IsChecked property. But I want the CheckBox to be checked when the form loads (when the first form is loaded).

How can I do this?

Below is the Xaml:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxCostsActiveOnly"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Width="74"
          Height="15"
          Margin="293,6,0,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Checked="CheckBoxActiveOnly_Checked"
          Content="Active Only"
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=CostsProgramVersionsActiveOnly, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Unchecked="CheckBoxActiveOnly_Unchecked" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this logic into your `ViewModel` and set the `CostsProgramVersionsActiveOnly` Property to `true` as soon as your `ViewModel` get initialized.

Comment: for that i need the property as InotifyPropertchanged member right??

Comment: Correct, see this tutorial please: http://wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html